Angular giving build errors when we serve

When we trying to serve the angular app it would not compile and gives errors as per the image. Other team members are on same angular cli versions are able to run it correctly without any errors. What could be possible reasons and solutions?
Package.json file
{
  "name": "angular-p",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve ",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasmine-auto-spies": "^6.9.9",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-verbose-reporter": "^0.0.8",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "14.0.0",
    "ngx-panzoom": "^16.0.0",
    "ngx-truncate-text": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "screenfull": "^6",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "jasmine": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}



Can you also provide the package.json? have you tried to delete the node_modules and package-lock.json, run npm i again and serve?

Can you provide the app.module.ts

@n_denny Yes I tried deleting node modules and package-lock.json and npm again. I can share but me and my teammate has the same files. It works there but does not work on my system so I assume it must be something related to local config

Provide Package,json file in you question please, what Node version are you using? what Angular version?

Edited the question to include package.json

Once I had this issue, actually with Angular Material. For me, it seems like after installing the library I had to restart the terminal. Maybe that's why it's running for your mate.

I see you have an old @angular/material version.
Try to update it to the correct version (@angular/material 16) that you need with angular 16

And @angular/cdk is old too.
